# How do I prevent Xcode from inserting a new line before a curly bracket after hitting return?

Tags: xcode, text, editing

In Xcode if I have:

```
foo}
```

and I insert my cursor just before the closing curly bracket and hit return, I get:

```
foo

}
```

What I would both expect (and desire) is to get:

```
foo
}
```

It feels like I've tried every single preference setting in the Text Editing pane to change this behavior with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I just learned you can press:
Option + Return

This will prevent insertion of the new line but also prevents indentation entirely.